# Java creating histogram method can someone help me to understand this code?

Tags: java, eclipse, histogram

```java
public class Library {
    
    public static int[] histogram(int a[],int M) {
        int[] newArr = new int[M];
        
        //Fill the new array
        try {
        if(a.length<M)
            System.out.println("Array lenght should be "
                    + "bigger than the number");
        else
            
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                int count = a[i];
                
                newArr[count] ++;
            }
        
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        //return the array
        return newArr;
    }
    
    public void printArray(int s[]) {
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(position+" ");
            position++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(s[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Library l1 = new Library();
        
        int J = 5;
        int[] w = {1,2,0,1,2,3};
        
        l1.printArray(histogram(w,J));
        
    }
}
```

I wrote this and some of the parts I looked at from google and other sources but I couldn't understand the else part in public static int[] histogram

```java
        else
            
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                int count = a[i];
                
                newArr[count] ++;
            }
```

How does this newArr[count] ++; works can someone explain to me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ` How does this newArr[count] ++; works can someone explain to me, please

Two thins are happening on this one line.

1. We get the reference to value in position `count` from `newArr` array.
2. We increment it by 1.

Therefore if you have array `newArr = [1,2,3]` calling `newArr[0]++` would result in you having the following state of `newArr` as `[2,2,3]`.

If something is still unclear, respond with a comment to this answer.

Comment: Yes I got the idea thanks and can you explain to me the  `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            int count = a[i]; ` part also because the count value will be equal to a[i]th value which is 1 because of the int[] w = {1,2,0,1,2,3}; then what's happening in the code

Comment: So what does a histogram show us ? It shows how often does a specific value occur in the measurement. We save the measurement value into the count variable ... and then newArr[count] contains information about how often we have seen a specific value, so we increment the value by one

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot actually so 'count' actually secure the value of a[i] which is let say 0, and the first variable in the array if a[4] is equal to count again it will newArr[count]++ and update our newArr[] then it will move on to a[1] then a[2], etc.

Comment: Great stuff. If your problem is solved please feel free to accept and upvote. This can help others find it and reuse it.